Connection 1-form associated to tensor product of connections
I'm not an expert on this topic so I need some guidance. I have a complex line vector bundle $$V\otimes \overline{\Bbb C}\to D,$$
where $\overline{\Bbb C}\to D$ is the trivial rank $1$bundle complex line bundle over the disk $D$, and $V$ is another complex line vector bundle over $D$. I have a connection $\nabla^V$ on $V\to D$, with connection $1$-form $$\theta\in \Omega^1(S(V),i\Bbb R)$$
(the form $\theta$ is defined on the sphere bundle of $V$ which coincides with the frame bundle as these are line bundle.

I'm taking a flat connection on the trivial bundle so I can define the connection on the tensor in the canonical way $$\nabla^{\otimes} = \nabla^V\otimes 1 + 1\otimes \nabla^{flat}$$
what is the connection $1$-form associated with it? It should be a form on $$\Omega^1(S(V\otimes \overline{C}),i\Bbb R)$$

What I think is $S(V\otimes \overline{C})=S(V)\otimes S(\overline{C})$, which would hint that an obvious answer would be $\theta\otimes \theta_{MC}$, the Mauer-Cartan form (which I believe is the associated connection $1$-form to the flat/trivial connection of $\overline{C}$).
Let me know if this makes sense, I'm very new to this field
